# How to reassemble packets with Java NIO Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, nio

If I have two connections to a server which require multiple reads on a channel to complete a packet, how will I know which read goes with which packet?

For example two packets which are received as four interleaved buffers:

- PacketA buffer part1
- PacketB buffer part1
- PacketA buffer part2
- PacketB buffer part2

The first part MAY have a header but the second part could arrive as being split anywhere along the packet.

When receiving a partial packet, how do I know which buffer goes where?

I'm thinking about building a map to associate each channel object with its respective output buffer which will hold the reassembled packet. Is this the way it's supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, typical practice is to have separate buffers for each channel. You don't necessarily need a map. You could [attach extra information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#attach-java.lang.Object-) to each `SelectionKey`. Every key can hold an object of your choice that your code can retrieve later. This is a convenient place to store a buffer, or a set of buffers.